# Determine the stability of the equilibrium points of the differential equation $\dot{x}=x(x-1)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I want to determine the stability of the equilibrium points of the equation $\dot{x}=x(x-1)$.

It is not difficult to see by drawing the phase line that $x=0$ is a sink and that $x=1$ is a source.

Intuitively this tells me that the solution $x=0$ is stable and that $x=1$ is unstable, but I wonder if there is a way to test it using Lyapunov's definition of stability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can use the definition of stability, this problem is better solved using Lyapunov functions.

Consider the equilibrium point $x_0=0$. The function $V_0(x)=x^2$ is a corresponding Lyapunov function as it is positive definite, continuously differentiable and its derivative along the trajectories
$$
\dot V_0= 2x\dot x= 2x^2(x-1)
$$
is negative in some deleted neighborhood of $x_0$. Hence, $x_0$ is an asymptotically stable equilibrium point.

Similarly, the function $V_1(x)=(x-1)^2$ is a Lyapunov function for the equilibrium point $x_1=1$. Its derivative along the trajectories
$$
\dot V_1= 2(x-1)\dot x= 2x(x-1)^2
$$
is positive in some deleted neighborhood of $x_1$, thus, $x_1$ is unstable.